# how to change the colour of a letter in a Text in QML

Tags: string, qt, text, colors, qml

```
Text {
    text: "Hello World!"
    font.family: "Helvetica"
    font.pointSize: 24
    color: "red"
}
```

Here when we say red the colour of the Full text tuens red.
How can we set **blue colour to the first letter H and remaining letters in red** using the above format?
Any ideas?

Comment: `text: "<font color='blue'>H</font>ello World!";  textFormat: Text.RichText`. More info [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#textFormat-prop)

Comment: thank you @eyllanesc

Comment: thank you @folibis